# Migrating from Access reports to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am migrating an application from Microsoft Access to a web based MVC 5/SQL Server one.

Access has a very easy to use report generation tool. It has headers and column headers on each printed page.

Most of the reports are just lists of names and numbers.

Is there a C# tool that can create similar output in PDF which I can use in MVC to generate the reports with headers on each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Templater.info 's tool. Simple for the needs of the project.

Answer (score 0):

[SSRS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) provides a lot of these features we have integrated them with our reporting services.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a tool like [PDF sharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) which is a .NET API for generating PDF's.  I believe there are some third party libraries like this too.